# Express multiple query parameters with same name does not return array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, query-string

With this url `http://example.com/users?test=1&test=2`

```
router.route('/users/?').get((req, res) => {
  console.dir(req.query) //=> { test : 1 }
})
```

returns `{ test : 1 }` instead of an array with `[ 1, 2 ]` as it should.

`?test[]=1&test[]=2` doesn't work either.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Why did you indicate `/?` in `'/users/?'`?

Comment: @Anatoly It used to be /users/:id? removed id and forgot to remove '/'. But it doesn't make a difference right?

Comment: II'm not sure. Just try simply `'/users'`

Comment: When I do this: `http://localhost/?test[]=1&test[]=2`, it works just fine for me.  `req.query` contains: `{ test: [ '1', '2' ] }`.  In fact, `http://localhost/?test=1&test=2` also generates the same `{ test: [ '1', '2' ] }` result for me.  I'm running Express 4.17.1.

Comment: @Anatoly No it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Also, check and make sure you don't have any query parser custom settings (the default is `extended`) as shown [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set).

Comment: @jfriend00 ok! I'm also running 4.17.1. Really strange. And whats even stranger is that when i test in postman i get: { test: 1 } and in the browser i get : { test: 2 }

Comment: Notice also, that I'm getting the results as strings and you are getting the results as numbers.  Something in your express configuration must have a different setting for how query parameters are parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do this: `http://localhost/?test[]=1&test[]=2`, it works just fine for me. `req.query` contains:

```
{ test: [ '1', '2' ] }.
```

In fact, `http://localhost/?test=1&test=2` also generates the same

```
{ test: [ '1', '2' ] }
```

result for me. I'm running Express 4.17.1.  So, if you have the proper Express configuration, it will work.

Notice also, that I'm getting the results as strings and you are getting the results as numbers so you are apparently not using the default Express parsing for query parameters.

Something in your express configuration must have a different setting for how query parameters are parsed.

Comment: Yes you where right! This is an old project and I totally missed that I used the hpp parameter pollution plugin. I have to whitelist the parameter name. Thanks for your help!